# Speakable items always activated after reboot

Tags: macos, accessibility

13" MBP running on OSX 10.8.2:

Problem is that after reboot Speakable items is always on. I have to go all the way to Settings - Accessibility - Speakable items to turn it off again. I don't know why it's turned on by default after reboot. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Systems Preference app preferences file, just like that of any other app, can become corrupted. There are utilities--none free that I know of--that will check your preferences files, or you can simply move this file from ~/Library/Preferences to the trash and see if that fixes the problem. Close System Preferences first.

And I assume you've checked your login items.

Comment: Problem did not go away immediately after taking the steps above, also not after reboot, but some longer time afterwards. Not sure why. Anyway (a late) thanks for the answer!

Comment: Post again if reappears. Maybe find & trash Speakable Items prefs ... also reset P-RAM.